# Sql developer PL SQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i execute a oracle procedure manually using execute proc_name, it is running fine. but when i try to do that from sql developer's procedures interface, I am getting the following error. Kindly help me on this

[image]

Comment: Why is the 'PL/SQL Block' section empty - that normally has a `begin`/`end` wrapper around your call. Did you delete what was in there? (Although I get an ORA-00900 if I do that, also reported against line 58; but other versions might throw a different error I suppose).

Comment: Edit your question and add your PL/SQL code

Answer (score 2):

By default the 'PL/SQL Block' section of that dialog box should contain something like:

```
BEGIN
  SSCI_FINDING_PROCEDURE();
--rollback
END;
```

But you can adapt it as needed, and any changes you make get saved between invocations. I don't think you can save it with nothing entered though. It might not be obvious why you can't just execute the procedure with no interaction at all, but if the procedure had any parameters, or it was a function, then you'd need a wrapper to define those. This is exactly what `execute` does under the hood - it just wraps whatever you're executing in a `BEGIN`/`END;`.

In version 4.0 (and 3.2, and 3.1) trying to OK that dialog with that section empty gives me an ORA-00900. Possibly you're using an older version that behaves differently. It might be nice if it warned you there was nothing to run rather than, apparently, passing the empty value to a JDBC call, but you can't have everything.

Comment: Hi Alex...My procedure has block like what u said...still it's not executing when i do throughh tool

Comment: @VinodChelladurai - I'm not referring to the procedure itself; I'm talking about the 'PL/SQL Block' section of the dialog you posted a picture of. Behind the 'PL/SQL Errors' pop-up, that part of the window is empty in your screenshot.

Comment: Hi Alex, i dont know why it is not showing there...i when i double clcik my procedure name on the interface , it is showing

Comment: @VinodChelladurai - when you double-click your procedure name you see the PL/SQL code *of that procedure*. When you run it (click the green arrow, or whatever) you get the 'Run PL/SQL' dialog box you showed above. *That dialog* has a 'PL/SQL Block' section, which you can see in your image. You can also see that it is empty. Paste in what I put in the answer, in that empty box, and then hit <OK>. Please be clear that I am not talking about your procedure code, and I am not saying to replace that code with this snippet; this is only to be used in that dialog to execute your existing procedure.